# Prove inequality $|tx+sy|^p\le t|x|^p+(1-t)|y|^p$

Tags: inequality

Prove inequality: for any $x,y,p,s\in\mathbb{R}$ with $p\ge 1$, $t \in [0,1]$, $s+t=1$:

$$|tx+sy|^p\le t|x|^p+(1-t)|y|^p$$

Attempts: I tried to define a function $f=|x|^p$ and tried to show that it is a convex function for $x>0$ but seem not work with $x\le 0$

Comment: What does not work for $x\leq 0$?

Comment: how can you prove that $f$ is covex for $x\le 0$?

Comment: E.g. check if the derivative is nondecreasing.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to show that $x^p$ is convex for $x\geq0$. Then when you replace $x$ with $|x|$, use the fact that composition of two convex functions(say f,g) with f nondecreasing is convex ($x^p$ is non decreasing for positive reals) . You dont have to worry about $x<0$ as the range of $|x|$ is the non-negative reals.

To prove $x^p$ is convex, for $p\geq2$, you can use the second derivative test. For p=1, it is linear. For $p \in (1,2)$, the first derivative yields $px^{p-1}$, which is monotonically increasing and hence, convex.

Comment: The composition of two convex functions is not necessarily convex..

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: I have taken back my vote. But in my world, "the first function" in a composition is the innermost..

Comment: Thanks Marten. I have cleared the ambiguity.